# How can i click in a dynamic element in selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

the class & aria label & data-nt si dynamic how can i click in it

```
<div class="_59k _2rgt _1j-f _2rgt" style="font-size: 17px;font-weight: 500;line-height: 20px;text-align: right;color: #050505" id="u_0_j_II" aria-label="عام" role="button" tabindex="0" data-nt="FB:TEXT4">عام</div>
```

Comment: Add some more of the HTML that wraps this element.  Is there a url we can go to to see this page? What code have you tried and what error are you getting?

Comment: Thats all element
https://prnt.sc/22zayug

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you try to copy the Xpath of the div? 

right click -> Copy -> Xpath 
and in python : driver.find_element(By.XPATH , ... )